# Cross domain jQuery ajax calls not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I'm having trouble with this code and I can't seem to get it to work. The typical error that I get back for this call is a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) " .

```
$('#btnZendesk').click(function () {
      $.ajax({
          url: "https://flatlandsoftware.zendesk.com/api/v2/topics/22505987.json",
          type: 'GET',
          crossDomain: true,
          xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
          },
          cache: false,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          processData: false,
          data: 'get=login',
          timeout: 2000,

          username: "test@test.com",
          password: "test",
          success: function (data, textStatus, response) {
              alert("success");
          },
          error: function (data, textStatus, response) {
              alert(data);
          }
      });
```

Comment: Same origin policy won't allow you to make cross-domain AJAX requests.

Comment: https://flatlandsoftware.zendesk.com/api/v2/topics/22505987.json resource is protected with Basic Authentication

Comment: Wrong password and username?

Comment: I've tried accessing that json file in my browser and it too says the request is unauthorized with those credentials. Please check your credentials.

Comment: @gronostaj that is incorrect if CORS is implemented.

Comment: How is CORS implemented?

Comment: @MichaelArnold see `crossDomain: true`

Answer (score 6):

Problem is that the resource you are trying to access is protected with Basic Authentication.

You can use `beforeSend` in jQuery callback to add a HTTP header with the authentication details e.g.:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXX"); 
}
```

Alternatively you can do it using jQuery `ajaxSetup`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: { 'Authorization': "Basic XXXXX" }
});
```

**EDIT**

A few links to the mentioned functions

- [jQuery.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)
- [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**EDIT 2**

The Authorization header is constructed as follows:

- Username and password are joined into a string `"username:password"` and the result string is encoded using **Base64**

Example:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not sure where to add in the beforesend fuction and where to input my password.  Would it be xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic myusername : mypassword")?

Comment: @Michael, I just added information how to generate basic auth. You were close. But do not put spaces around : and use Base64 after on final string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  Unfortunately, now I've run into a deeper problem and it seems that zendesk doesn't allow cross-domain AJAX requests.  Too bad I didn't read the fine-print before signing up ;)

Answer (score 0):

I too got this problem and somehow all solutions from internet either failed or were not applicable due to client webservice restrictions (JSONP, XDR, CORS=true)

For this, I added an iframe in my page which resided in the client;s server. So when we post our data to the iframe and the iframe then posts it to the webservice. Hence the cross-domain referencing is eliminated.

We added a 2-way origin check to confirm only authorized page posts data to and from the iframe.

Hope it helps

```
<iframe style="display:none;" id='receiver' name="receiver" src="https://iframe-address-at-client-server">
 </iframe>

//send data to iframe
var hiddenFrame = document.getElementById('receiver').contentWindow;
hiddenFrame.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message), 'https://client-server-url');

//The iframe receives the data using the code:
window.onload = function () {
    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var eventer = window[eventMethod];
    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
    eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
        var origin = e.origin;
        //if origin not in pre-defined list, break and return
        var messageFromParent = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var json = messageFromParent.data;

        //send json to web service using AJAX   
        //return the response back to source
        e.source.postMessage(JSON.stringify(aJAXResponse), e.origin);
    }, false);
}
```